# authlogic single access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I am using Single access token to do some data transfer, so far I got it to work with one action in the controller through

**ProjectsController**

```
private

def single_access_allowed?
  action_name == 'index'
end
```

But I need two more actions to be allowed access with single access token, I tried to modify the line `action_name == 'index'` to `action_name == ['index', 'update', 'destroy']` but to no avail. I have tried to look for the single_access_allowed? definition in all of the files in authlogic's gem directory, but it doesn't say what sort of variable action_name is, e.g., array, hash, string?

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action_name` is a string. You want to check if `action_name` is within a list of actions (an array of strings). To do this in ruby:

```
def single_access_allowed?
  ["index","update","destroy"].include?(action_name)
end
```

Comment: Oh I see, the '==' operator returns a true/false value, that's why it was 'action_name == "index"', Thanks very much!